# How to add left right, right left sliding in bottom navigation in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

Here is the XML code to perform bottom navigation:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/bottom_navigation_height"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:elevation="3dp"
    app:itemBackground="@color/colorWhite"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_nav_selector"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_nav_text_selector"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu" />
```

And this is the Java code to remove shift able mode:

```
 BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    BottomNavigationViewHelper.removeShiftMode(bottomNavigationView);
```

I want to add a left-right slide.  Here I add a Listener on the Bottom navigation menu here is my code.

`bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {`